# Interesting issue with an accepted answer that I've never encountered before

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

So, I answered a question a few days ago, and it was accepted.  Then today, the OP decided that it did not fit his requirements and removed my answer as the accepted answer.  He said that he did this to raise attention to his question again, but while being similar, his *new* is in fact a very different one.

Is there any way to discourage this kind of action, or is it in fact acceptable?

Comment: It is entirely up to the OP to award or retract the Accept Answer mark. The OP gives and the OP taketh away.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, it's acceptable to completely change a question after already accepting an answer?  That just seems like an easy way to abuse the system and the answerer(s). Not saying you're wrong, it just seems messed up.

Comment: whereas bait-and-switch is frowned upon... I don't know if there is anything you can do other than ask the OP to open a new question for his new problem. If you explain the usefulness of your answer to other users who may encounter the same issue he might understand and revert his question to it's original form, then open a new one.

Comment: @SteveP.: If the question was *changed*, see the duped question.

Comment: In general it is highly discouraged (if not simply against the rules) to change a question completely, but that's not what happened here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958062/change-the-date-format/17958179). Looking at the edit, the OP simply amended his question. Granted, that changes the answer, but I don't think this sort of edit is a problem. The issue is that the OP should not have accepted your answer to begin with since his question was not complete. As for un-accepting to draw more attention to the question -- that's kind of rude, but certainly acceptable.

Comment: @BenLee Fair enough, ok.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is indeed a duplicate of the chameleon questions post, or at least as close as one can reasonably get.  I voted to close.  Thank you.

Comment: @BenLee rude, for sure. But this is one of the problems created by  badgering OPs to accept their answer right at the 15 minute mark. New users are trained into believing that the right behavior is to accept an answer as soon as possible, when that is actually not in the best interests of anyone except the person who gets the checkmark. In most cases that check mark won't change because it's rude. Catch-22.